# use a run-time value in template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers, sorting

Please consider class `A`, and the function object `A_less`. `A_less` compares two `A` pointers, depending on the result of `A::getvalue()`.

```
class A {
    int getvalue(const string &Parameter);
};

struct A_less : public binary_function<A *, A *, bool> {
    A_less(const string &P) : Parameter(P) { }
    bool operator()(const A *lhs, const A *rhs) const {
        return A->getvalue(Parameter) < rhs->getvalue(Parameter);
    }
    string Parameter;
}
```

How do I go about declaring/creating sorted containers (sets, priority_queues, ...), of `A` pointers, sorted by `A_less` depending on specific (run-time) values of `Parameter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
std::string p = ...;
std::set<A,A_less> m(A_less(p));
```

You have to specify the template parameter `Compare` (which is 2nd for `set`). When constructing a map, you need to give the comparison function object to the constructor of `map`.

Comment: Nice, now I see what the `set(Compare &comp)` ctor is needed for. Compiles nicely with gcc, the MS compiler has some warning C4930: 'std::set<_Kty,_Pr> T(A_less)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?).